# state set inside react-query useQuery hook reseting to initial state on windows focus

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state, react-query

I have this code, that on the first build works fine

```
const [conditionState, setConditionState] = useState([])

const { data: solicitud, error } = useQuery(['SOLICITUD', _id], async () => {
     const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/solicitudes/${_id}`);

    setConditionState(data.condiciones)
    return data.solicitud;
}, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
})
if (error) console.log(error);
```

The problem is that, when I change tabs and back to the application (re-focusing on the app window) the conditionState is set back to it initial state, iI understand that the code inside the useQuery hook is not running again due to the refetchOnWindowsFocus being false, but isn't the useState hook supposed to be the last state before updating, which supposedly should be data.condiciones?

Btw solicitud still the same after the refocus, is there something about the hooks that I'm not understanding?

Comment: It is very hard to understand the flow by how you explained it. Which tabs? Can you show a wider snippet?

Comment: i meant changing tabs in the browser, for example changing to gmail and then back to the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way the conditionState is set back to the initial state is because the component got remounted. Something is triggering a re-rendering from the top tree of this component.

Comment: so, the browser tab changing isnt triggering the re-rendering? Then it may be a useSession hook higher up in the component tree that is causing it. I will check the component hierarchy to see from where it re-renders

Comment: Maybe some parent does have a refetchOnWindowFocus, causing a re rendering on this component. Of that is the case, you can avoid it with React.memo()

Comment: yeah, it was the way we were creating the component in the granparent component, it was dependant on the url, so it read the url read and rendered the component, i fixed it with useCallback so it wont re-render each time, thanks you for helping, it helped a lot in pin pointing the error (upvoted your answer but i dont have rep enough)

Comment: Glad to hear. My pleasure to help.